# JSF tags not being rendered as HTML

Tags: jsf, netbeans, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm following the **Java EE firstcup** tutorial using **Netbeans** and **Glassfish**.

When I execute the JSF web tier I've been instructed to code, the browser gets the same JSF markup coded in the .xhtml file, and the tags are not rendered as HTML tags. I know this by using the *view source code* in my browser.

For example, for this code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Page title here</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h2>
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.WelcomeMessage}" />
        </h2>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The browser should get something like:

```
<html ...>
    <head>
        <title>Page title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>
            the welcome message goes here
        </h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Right?

Well, my browser is getting jsf code (the first piece of code above) and not the html code (the second piece of code above).

It seems to be a configuration problem in netbeans or glassfish but don't know what. Any ideas?

---

This is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/firstcup/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>greetings.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is my faces-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!-- =========== FULL CONFIGURATION FILE ================================== -->

<faces-config version="2.0"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>firstcup.web.WebMessages</base-name>
            <var>bundle</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
    </application>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/greetings.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/response.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

---

Moreover:

- The url I'm entering in the browser is http://localhost:8081/firstcup/ but I've also tried: http://localhost:8081/firstcup/greetings.xhtml
- I've checked Glassfish logs and there's no information about not being able to load FacesServlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Changing the **welcome-file** in **web.xml** to the following solved the problem:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>firstcup/greetings.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Odd. You told that you've tried `http://localhost:8081/firstcup/greetings.xhtml` as well. That should have worked as well without a welcome file. At least, the root cause of the problem is still that the request was **not** been passed through the `FacesServlet`.

Answer (score 20):

If JSF tags are not been parsed, then it simply means that the request has not been passed through the `FacesServlet`. That servlet is the one responsible for all that JSF stuff. You need to verify if the request URL used matches the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet`. Note that it is case sensitive.

This may however also happen if you opened the file *directly* in the builtin browser of the IDE. You shouldn't do that. You need to specify the right URL yourself in the address bar of either the builtin browser or an external browser (e.g. MSIE/Firefox).

**Update**: one more thing, did you declare the JSF HTML taglib in `<html xmlns>` attribtue? You omitted that in your code snippet.

It should look like

```
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked it and the url pattern was wrong. I've change it to /firstcup/*. However, the url I'm entering is http://localhost:8081/firstcup/ after restarting the server and re-deploying the application, but but I keep getting the un-rendered jsf code. What else could it be?

Comment: Sorry, the url i'm entering in the browser is localhost:8081/firstcup with a slash (/) at the end (I don't know why that last slash is not being shown in the comment)

Comment: That slash doesn't matter. Maybe the `FacesServlet` failed to start for some reason. Read the server startup logs to know more.

Comment: Yes, I included the xmlns attributes (I've updated the question).

Comment: Nothing about FacesServlet in glassfish logs.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for your accurate and detailed answer. Saved my day.

Answer (score 9):

The following code in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

instead of `faces/*` has solved my problem of non-rendered jsf tags.

Note: `*.html` causes stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Check either your web.xml or your faces-config.xml. Something's obviously missing.

edit :
i don't know jsf 2, but in my jsf 1 faces-config.xml i have this :

```
<application>
   <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

Maybe you should take a look a this. (could be a hint, sorry i cannot help any further)

edit 2 : this is not the answer, sorry

Comment: What should I check there? I'm a newbie to jsf and j2ee and I've every thing the tutorial says regarding the web.xml and the faces-config.xml. That is: set the welcome page in the web.xml, set the resourse bundle for localization purposes in the faces-config.xml and set some pageflow properties in the faces-config.xml.

Comment: Show us those two files, that'll help.

Comment: @Eligriv: that's not needed in JSF 2.0 as Facelets is the default view handler.

Comment: ah, see, i'm short of ideas then :p sorry

Comment: This is the helpful solution for people searching the same problem in JSF 1.2

Answer (score 0):

I have also suffered from problem of `jsf tags`, not rendered at all. I used welcome file in `web.xml` as `login/entry.xhtml`.

When I changed that file to `faces/login/entry.xhtml`, it is working well.

It must be due to `facesServelet` is `not intercepting` the page.
It leads to rendering of only plain **html** and **jsf** tags are simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be relevant to you, but after hours of searching for the solution for a similar problem, my culprit turns out to be this file in WEB-INF/faces-config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config version="1.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"/>
```

For some strange reason JBoss Tools 3.3.0.M2 put that file in my JSF 2.0 project and BOOM! Nothing works. The file looks very innocent yet (probably due to version="1.2") it made me quite frustrated.

I've searched logs (nothing!), WEB-INF/lib, classpaths, even removing dependencies and it turned out to be a single faces-config.xml :-P

Hopefully this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @hendy-irawan

I solved my issue by changed my faces-config header

From

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">

</faces-config>
```

To

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem.  I deleted some richfaces jars from the WEB-INF/lib and JSF is working now.