# Eclipse not rendering jsf?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat

only tomcat server will display the .jsf pages correctly. When I try to add project through eclipse and view and test it doesn't render the .jsf code but instead displays it as source code. I have eclipse configured for tomcat and that works fine but can't get the .jsf pages to render it just displays the source code when added to the server through eclipse but if I export the .war file and run it on tomcat/webapps then it works fine.

source code example from eclipse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
      <title>PCC Accounts Login</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:outputStylesheet name="style.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
<h:outputText>testing output text tag WITHOUT using value attributeHELLo ????</h:outputText>
<h:outputText value="testing outputText WITH using the value attribute" />
<h:form>
  <h:inputText id="user_id" title="User Name" value="User Name" action="#{loginBean.setUsername}">User Name</h:inputText>
  <h:inputText id="password" title="Password" value="Password" action="#{loginBean.setPassword}">Password</h:inputText>
  <!-- <h:commandButton id="login" value="Login" action="accounts.jsf">Login Now</h:commandButton> -->
  <h:commandButton id="login" value="Login" action="accounts.jsf" />
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

source code example exported from eclipse and ran on tomcat:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="j_idt2">
  <title>PCC Accounts Login</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assign05_test/javax.faces.resource/style.css.jsf" />
</head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt9" value="j_idt9" />
<input id="j_idt9:user_id" type="text" name="j_idt9:user_id" value="User Name" title="User Name" />
<input id="j_idt9:password" type="text" name="j_idt9:password" value="Password" title="Password" />
<input id="j_idt9:login" type="submit" name="j_idt9:login" value="Login" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

SO, Eclipse is obviously not rendering the JSF pages but I added the correct file to the  Preferences/Java/BuildPath/UserLibraries. So I'm not sure why it's not working but for now I'm testing by exporting the .war then running it on tomcat server which is very tedious process. Anybody else run into this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Respectfully,
Martin Hand

Comment: Can you add your web.xml file also?

Comment: see if this works.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207616/jsf-tags-not-being-rendered-as-html

Comment: @EvesMary Yeessss! that article helped and it worked, my instructor said to add url mapping *.jsf in web.xml and thats what I did but I changed it to `<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>` and its fixed. I had `<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>` in there before but was told I needed that to invoke the jsf engine.Guess not, THANKS!

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could mark my post as a useful post.

Answer (score 0):

Had this for servlet-mapping in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Changed it to this and it's fixed:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Funny though that it only affected it when trying to run through Eclipse but if exported `.war` then added to `/webapps` in tomcat it was fine but that's a very tedious and annoying process when trying to develope an application. Also read this helpful article if your having trouble - [JSF tags not being rendered as HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207616/jsf-tags-not-being-rendered-as-html)

Comment: what url are you using ? does it end with .xhtml ? are you using some kind of ULR-Rewrite ?